# How to get username confirmation from LDAP using ldapTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I've been searching for a way to validate a username with LDAP using the spring ldapTemplate.

My search led me to

```
ldapTemplate.search(base, filter, contextMapper/AttributeMapper)
```

But i'm wondering what i need to put in the contextMapper or attributeMapper. From what i've read, it is used to map the data to an object. But I dont need the object. I only want a boolean to know if it exists or not.

An example of my attributes:

```
base="ou=accounts,dc=example,dc=local"
// Replace $1 with the username we'd like to find.
filter="(&amp;(objectclass=Person)(sAMAccountName=$1))"
```

My template contains the url, username and password and connection has been established.

I could use a little help as i'm not sure if using the search method is the right way to go here.

I have authentication set up with the ldapTemplate and would like to re-use it.

thanks

Comment: My guess is that the filter should be `(&(objectclass=Person)(sAMAccountName=$1))` because LDAP will not understand HTML entities.

Comment: Well it doesn't give any problems in my authenticate method so... We'll see if it gives an error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to either

- implement `ContextMapper` in your own class which will process the search results, or
- use [`LdapEntryIdentificationContextMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapEntryIdentificationContextMapper.html) to hold the received entries.

For the latter, just create an empty instance using `new LdapEntryIdentificationContextMapper();` and add that to your `search()` call. The result will be an instance of `List<LdapEntryIdentification>` which you can walk through.

Comment: But this will return the user with all his info?
Isn't there a way to get the LDAP to just return true or false if the user exists? I dont need the user locally and would like to avoid it as it could be a security risk.

Also my apologies for taking so long to answer, i coulden't log on during the weekend.

Comment: Ok so i used the search function with a context mapper which only returned the username and used that to validate. So i got it working.

But just to be sure: So there is no way to ask the LDAP does this user exist? Meaning getting a boolean value returned. You always have to ask: Give me this user if he exists?

Comment: The answer is yes, no boolean :) LDAP is basically a search protocol, so you search for a user and get zero or more results. You can limit the amount of data returned to only the DN, which is what you want. Use `getRelativeName()` of your `LdapEntryIdentification` to get to the DN.